# Microsoft Identity - IdentityUserLogins table, what's it for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I noticed an `IdentityUserLogins` table that seems to be untouched in my application... what is it supposed to be for?

I have got users, they have roles, when they log in, I see nothing end up in here.

I have searched on Bing and could not find much on it:

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is used to store information about external logins such as Facebook, google, etc.